# Save data on sim card using micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, interface, sim, data-storage

SIM cards come in various data capacities, from 8 KB to at least 256 KB. All allow a maximum of 250 contacts to be stored on the SIM,

Is it possible to save data (other then contacts) in sim card, interfacing it with micro-controller then transfer data from micro-controller to sim card?

Comment: May I ask why? There are much more appropriate and easy to work with media types.

Comment: Spot on @EugeneSh - OP, please can you expand your question to give all the background details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  Except I am not sure if you are referring to smart cards or mobile specific SIM cards.

Smart Cards are easy.  They are like any other memory device.

If you need to access a SIM card from a mobile phone it can get a bit more difficult as it becomes carrier and phone vendor specific.

For mobile SIM cards, I found it easiest to use a GMS modem module. You can use the serial port of the µController to communicate with the GSM module.